# alterar classes com angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, front-end

Eu preciso mudar o estilo de um elemento quando clicado e se clicar de novo ele volta pra cor que tava (como se fosse uma "busca avançada"). 
Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<a href="" class="corCinza" ng-click="exibirForm = !exibirForm">...</a>
<div class="filtro" ng-show="exibirForm">
    <form ... /> 
</>
```

Quando eu clicar no `<a>` ele tem que ficar com corAzul e abrir a div com o form. Se eu clicar de novo ele fecha a div do form e volta a corCinza.
O form já está funcionando, mas eu não consegui mudar a cor. 
Tentei usar o ng-class como num "tutorial" mas não funcionou.
Alguém pode me ajudar? 
P.S.: Eu só "programo" html e css. O máximo que codei foi um helloWorld simples em JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `ng-class` que trabalha com condição, alterando a classe do elemento. Exemplo:

```
<a href="" class="corCinza" ng-class="{'corAzul': !exibirForm}" ng-click="exibirForm = !exibirForm">
```

Quando `exibirForm` for `false`, a classe `corAzul` será adicionada.

Você também pode utilizar com mais de uma definição de classe, caso queira remover a classe existente, por exemplo:

```
<a href="" ng-class="{'corCinza': exibirForm, 'corAzul': !exibirForm}" ng-click="exibirForm = !exibirForm">
```

Deste modo ele só exibe uma classe por vez.

Comment: Nossa @CelsomTrindade, eu estava pensando em soluções "mais complexas". Isso funcionou muito bem. Obrigada!

Comment: Não por isso ;) Apenas lembre-se: classe definida dentro de `class=""` é estática, não pode ser removida através do `ng-class`. Classe definida dentro do `ng-class=""` somente será adicionada ao `class=""` se a condição conferir.

Comment: Ook!! Mais uma vez obrigada! :D

Comment: @trofonia se resolveu o problema, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita =D